# I want to change my Application name programmatically ie name which is present below app installed on home screen using Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin

I want to set my Application name pro-grammatically IE name which is present below app installed on home screen using Xamarin Android.For example i want to set it with any string value given by programmer in my Main Activity File

Comment: It is not possible  Programatically. Because `AndroidManifest` have a fix `string` which is not changing in `RunTime`.

Comment: Can we do it from seperate program or command prompt??

Comment: @ankitvishen  In Xamarin android you can not change the app name programmatically or command. But If you do java android development it is possible to change the app name by Gradle.

Comment: Come on guys If you Have answer kindly give it.,Otherwise don't mark it as duplicate because solution on that page isn't the one i need

Comment: I found a solution ,You Can Change App Name by Creating A constant identifier String in Static Class And in Your AssemblyInfo.cs make these changes [assembly: AssemblyTitle("YourConstantStringReference")]